# Variable values

Tags: python

```
from sys import exit
haskey = 0

# start function
def start():
print "You wake up in an empty room, feels like you've been here for days. You can't         remember anything from your past. All there is in the room is a digital clock. It says 3:26am, May 5, 2012. Get out of the room?"

next = raw_input("> ").lower()
if "yes" in next:
    lobby()
elif "no" in next:
    print "We insist"
else:
    print "Try again."

def lobby():
while True:
    print "You arrived at a lobby, all you can see are four doors. Which door   to enter? (first, second, third, fourth)?"

    next = raw_input("> ").lower()
    if "first" in next:
        firstdoor()
    elif "second" in next:
        seconddoor()
    elif "third" in next:
        thirddoor()
    elif "fourth" in next:
        fourthdoor()
    else:
        print "Are you dumb and you can't even follow instructions?"

def firstdoor():
print "You arrive at another empty room, examine further or exit?"
choice = raw_input("> ").lower()
if "examine" in choice:
    print "A trap door opened, you fell in it and died."
    exit()
elif "exit" in choice:
    lobby()
else:
    print "Are you dumb and you can't even follow instructions?"

def seconddoor():
print "You arrive at the study room, examine room or exit?"
choice = raw_input("> ").lower()
if "examine" in choice:
    print "There is a note on the table, read it?"
    secondchoice = raw_input("> ").lower()
    if "yes" in secondchoice:
        note()
    elif "no" in secondchoice:
        print "Returning to lobby."
        lobby()

def note():
print """Security Log (040412): A man from the city travelling along the highway loses control of his vehicle and fell to the cliff. He was able to jump and grab a hold to the bushes growing at the side of the cliff. We were able to rescue him, but as soon as we secured him to the ground he violently reacted to our help and fainted. A few minutes later he was out of control, like he was possessed by a demon. We had no choice but to sedate him and keep him locked in our prison until authorities from the city arrive and examine him. The key to his cell is in the vault in the vault room. The keycode changes depending on the current date.
"""
print "Returning to lobby."
lobby()

def thirddoor():
if haskey == 0:
    print "Door is locked, you need a key to continue."
    print "%d" % haskey
    lobby()
elif haskey == 1:
    exit()

def exit():
print "You are now free!"
print "To be continued.."

def fourthdoor():
print "There is a vault inside the room. Use vault?"
usevault = raw_input("> ")
if "yes" in usevault:
    vault()
else:
    print "Returning to lobby.."
    lobby()

def vault():
while True:
    print "There is a security code for this door. Enter code:"
    code = raw_input("> ")
    if "05042012" in code:
        print "Correct!"
        print "Returning to lobby.."
        haskey = int(1)
        print "%d" % haskey
        lobby()
    else:
        print "Code Error! Try again?"

start()
```

I have this mini-text game for a tutorial on python and I'm using the fourthdoor/vault function to ask the player the code and if entered correctly it changes the value of a variable to be used as a key to open the third door. The problem is even if the value of the variable is changed when the vault code is given correctly, I still can't open the door.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try to make your questions concise. Most people don't want to read lots of code, so if you can isolate the problem and post only the code needed to explain it, you're more likely to get a response.

Comment: "Ouch!", said the stack.

Comment: also, no one wants to read code that wide. keep your lines short.

Comment: @Wooble +1. **Limit all lines to a maximum of 79 characters.** PEP8: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length

Answer (score 0):

When python encounters `haskey = int(1)` inside of `vault`, it creates a new local variable called `haskey` that you can only see inside of `vault`. You need to tell python that when it sees `haskey` in that function, you mean the global `haskey` that you declare at the top of the file. You can do this by adding `global haskey` to the beginning of `vault`. ie:

```
def vault():
    global haskey
    while True:
        print "There is a security code for this door. Enter code:"
        code = raw_input("> ")
        ...
```

Comment: Also there's no reason to call `int(1)`, ever. Just use `1`

Comment: There are plenty of other things wrong with the code, I decided to keep the scope of my post narrow. :)